# Can the likelihood ratio estimate multivariate confidence levels?

Tags: confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis, mixture-distribution, likelihood, hessian

Wilks' theorem describes the log-ratio between the highest likelihood of a distribution $\mathcal{L}$ (aka the dominant mode, given at $\vec{x}_{m}$) and the likelihood of a distribution at a given point $\vec{x}$:
\begin{equation}
D=2\left(\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}_{m}))-\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}))\right)
\end{equation}
Observe that $\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}_{m}))-\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}))$ can be written using Taylor's expansion for $\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}))$:
\begin{equation}
[\vec{x}_{m}-\vec{x}]\nabla \log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}_{m}))+\frac{1}{2}[\vec{x}_{m}-\vec{x}]^T \mathbb{H}(x) [\vec{x}_{m}-\vec{x}]
\end{equation}
With $\mathbb{H}(x)$ as the Hessian matrix. The first therm is null, since the dominant mode is at the maximum of the log likelihood and therefore the gradient of $\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}_{m}))$ is null.
Therefore, Wilks' theorem can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
D=[\vec{x}_{m}-\vec{x}]^T \mathbb{H}(x) [\vec{x}_{m}-\vec{x}]
\end{equation}
In statistics there is a strong relationship between the Hessian and the covariance matrix. More precisely, the Hessian matrix is equal to the inverse of the covariance matrix.
For a uni-modal Gaussian the Hessian is $\mathbb{H}(x)=\mathbb{S}^{-1}$, with $\mathbb{S}$ as the covariance matrix.
The dominant mode for a uni-modal Gaussian can be found at $\vec{\mu}$.
For this case Wilks' theorem can be written as:
\begin{equation}
D= [\vec{\mu}-\vec{x}]^T \mathbb{S}^{-1} [\vec{\mu}-\vec{x}]
\end{equation}
Which follows a $\chi^2$-law:
\begin{equation}
D \sim \chi^2(df)
\end{equation}
By using this one can estimate the confidence level:
\begin{equation}
\chi^2_{CDF}(2\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}_{m}))-2\log(\mathcal{L}(\vec{x}))) = q_x
\end{equation}
But is this also true for other distributions (e.g. a mixture of Gaussians)?

Comment: After some experiments I can conclude that Wilk's theorem seems to work fine for parabolic likelihood functions (Gaussian) and is still a remarkable accurate estimation for non-parabolic but convex likelihood functions. But this method does not work for non-convex likelihood functions (multimodal functions).